# Root lost After Reboot

Tags: rooting, root-access, stock-android

I tried to root my phone and it worked only with [Kingo Root](http://www.kingoapp.com/) and after I reboot my phone, I do not have root-access. I have tried several times, please answer me. I really need to root my phone. It's [Vonino Jax QS](http://www.specificatii.com/gadgeturi/vonino/jax-qs_3840.html).

Comment: You don't have root access how? You no longer have the GUI app? Binary errors? Root can't be undone with factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

If Kingo root can't help you root successfully. You can try another tool like iRoot.I once used and found it do no harm to my device.Try as this guide:
[one click root to root Android phones and tablets](http://www.iroot.com/how-to-articles/one-click-root-android-phone-and-tablet.html)